# Finding the shortest path in the presence of negative cycles

Tags: ds.algorithms, graph-algorithms, shortest-path

Given a directed cyclic graph where the weight of each edge may be negative the concept of a "shortest path" only makes sense if there are no negative cycles, and in that case you can apply the Bellman-Ford algorithm.

However, I'm interested in finding the shortest-path between two vertices that doesn't involve cycling (ie. under the constraint that you may not visit the same vertex twice). Is this problem well studied? Can a variant of the Bellman-Ford algorithm be employed, and if not is there another solution?

I'm also interested in the equivalent all-pairs problem, for which I might otherwise apply Floyd–Warshall.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Paths with no repeated vertices are called [simple-paths](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_%28graph_theory%29#Different_types_of_paths), so you are looking for the shortest simple-path in a graph with negative-cycles.

This can be reduced from the [longest-path problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem).  If there were a fast solver for your problem, then given a graph with only positive edge-weights, negating all the edge-weights and running your solver would give the longest path in the original graph.

Thus your problem is NP-Hard.

Comment: This is a beautiful answer. I've asked several people this IRL without any solutions and when I explained this to them their reaction was the same as mine - "of course, I feel so stupid now".